# How to use window.onerror with React?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

The idea is to catch an error and then handle the information caught by the handler. But it propagate it anyway and I don't know how to stop it.

Say, I have a component and I just want to have more information about error. For some reason, if I use try-catch, the error object doesn't show the line number - unlike the window.onerror. But when I use onerror handler, it bubbles the exception and it's caught higher what is not the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the [error-boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) of React?
Have you tried this?

Comment: No, I didn't try it yet. I was trying to handle the error with window.onerror because it gets the most full information. Do you think error wrapping component would help?

Comment: It definitely helps to contain it within part of the page. Try it first, maybe it solve your problem

Comment: I wrapped my component with ErrorBoundary and all the exceptions are now caught by this. Thanks!